# Number of conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups of order $pq$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \times GL_m(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

**First question:** Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct prime numbers, and let $m$ and $n$ be positive 
integers. How many conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups of order $pq$ does
the group
$$
  {\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \times {\rm GL}_m(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})
$$
have?

**Second question:** Let $p$ a prime numbers and $k$ be positive integer such that $(k, p) = 1$. And $m$ be the order of $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}^×$. How many conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups of order $k$ does
the group
$$
  {\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}) 
$$
have?

Comment: We know of course the number of conjugacy-classes of cyclic subgroups in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ see :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32931/conjugacy-classes-of-subgroups-in-gln-p?rq=1

Comment: Thank you very much.Have you the proof for the fact that the conjugacy classes of a direct product are direct products of conjugacy classes of the factors,

Comment: It follows directly from the relevant definitions that $(g,h)^{G\times H} = g^G \times h^H$.

Comment: Can you give a reference to this definition.

Comment: Ok, I realize that my earlier comments where not precisely to the point since you are asking about conjugacy classes of *subgroups*, not of elements. Conjugacy classes of elements in a direct product are itself direct products of conjugacy classes, but for classes of subgroups it's different. And getting from classes of elements to classes of cyclic subgroups is in general not so straightforward as for order $p$ in characteristic $p$.

Comment: See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_conjugacy_classes_in_a_direct_product_is_the_product_of_the_number_of_conjugacy_classes_in_each_factor